concyclicity related to the Humpty point
$AD$ and $CE$ are the altitudes of triangle $ABC$, $M$ is the midpoint of $AC$. Circumcircles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ of triangles $AEM$ and $CDM$, respectively, intersect at point $P$. $CP$ and $AP$ intersect $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, respectively, second time at points $X$ and $Y$. Prove that $B, P, X, Y$ are concyclic.

My progress:
I was able to prove that $P$ is the Humpty point:
By the radical center theorem, three radical axes of the circles $(AEPM)$, $(MPDC)$, $(AEDC)$ intersect in one point - $B$. This means that $P$ lies on the median $BM$.  Next we can conclude that $∠MPC = ∠MDC = ∠MCD$, which means that $∠PBC = ∠PCM$. Similarly, $∠PBA = ∠PAM$, and this is the defifniton of the B-Humpty point. That means that all of its properties are true: if $H$ is the orthocenter, then $E, B, D, P, H$ are concyclic; $A, H, P, C$ are concyclic; $HP ⊥ BM$. Well, now we have better understnding of what the point $P$ is. But what can we say about $X$ and $Y$? We need to prove that $∠XBY + ∠XPY = 180°$, but we know that $∠XPY + ∠ABC = 180°$, so we should prove that $∠XBY = ∠ABC$. I can't say this made the problem any easier, so I am stuck here. Thanks for any help!
Here is the GeoGebra link.

I have found that the A-Humpty point (not a common terminology : you should have defined it at first !) can be also defined in a more handy way as the projection of the orthocenter onto the median issued from A. Moreover, I have found a good reference for the Humpty-Dumpty points with properties : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c698232h1693635

Hello, thank you very much! By the way, in my attempt I've mentioned that HP ⊥ BM, which means that P is the projection from the orthocenter to the median. Probably, I really should have included more information about the Humpty point itself, but we have learned about it at school, so I didn't think it is so uncommon.

Thank you for your answer ; the problem for me when I read your text is that I was confused by the term "the Humpty point" as if it is unique for the triangle (as the orthocenter, the incenter etc.), instead of using the term "B-Humpty point", or the Humpty point relative to (the median issued from) $B$.


In picture perpendicular bisectors of PY and PX intersect at K. We draw a circle on K passing point X, Y and P. This circle intersect circumcircle of ABC at a point like B'.Since circles $w_1$ and $w_3$ intersect circumcircle at points A and C, then the intersection of $w_2$ and circumcircle must be the third vertex B because other two circles pass P and a vertex of triangle.

Hello! Thank you for your solution, but unfortunately I couldn't understand it. For example, if we will apply your logic for any other point P' on the median BM, it should work: Let perpendicular bisectors of P'Y and P'X intersect at point K. We'll draw a circle $ω_3$ with center K that passes through X, Y and P'. Since circumcircles of triangles AP'M and CP'M pass through P' and vertex of triangle, then the circle $ω_3$ must pass through the third vertex B, which is not true, as you can see on the diagram here: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/x6jsfefw. Have I misunderstood something?

@Meison, You are welcome. the circles must also pass the feet of altitudes of triangle so that lines passing M and P also P and X, and P and Y become radical axis of intersecting circles. I do not see that in your construction. That is P is unique and cannot be arbitrary.

Thanks, got it now!

Please, see the reference I just gave above.
